# jQuery keyup character error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting strange characters when the keyup event is fired.
For example pressing `-` shows up as `½` on screen.

`$('#c').append(String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase());`

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a problem whith your keyboard configuration? i mean, maybe it's in other "lenguage", try in another application

Comment: Nope, this is as expected, I'm assuming you're trying to do this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6xHpC/**

Comment: just seems like the wrong way of doing it all together. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `keypress` event, not the `keyup` or `keydown` events, as those would cause this exact problem.

change :

```
$('#a').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $('#c').append(String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xHpC/)

to :

```
$('#a').on('keypress', function(e) {
    $('#c').append(String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xHpC/1/)